# Is there a YII skeletion framework that fully shows the functionality?

Tags: php, yii

So that I can see all its features and get familiar with it by debug once line by line?

Comment: I've started building a site that will, eventually, demonstrate the cool stuff you can do with Yii. It's at http://yiipis.com. The code is on github, link on the site.

Answer (score 0):

Simply.  No.  I wish I could say yes, but there simply isn't.

Answer (score 0):

if you downloaded the latest yii distribution, you can check the demos\ folder, there are a couple of working demos there, simple ones though :p

Answer (score 0):

The Yii demos showcase *basic* functionality. To my knowledge there is nothing that demos all that Yii can do, and if there were it would need to be so complicated that it would have no benefit as a tutorial.

It's best if you focus on one thing at a time and look for examples on that specifically. And don't forget that the best way of learning is by getting your own hands dirty!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this will help
http://code.google.com/p/yiiplayground/

and here's the demo
http://www.yiiplayground.cubedwater.com/

Very basic, but very helpful